# regex filter in TinyMCE importcss_groups function

Tags: javascript, regex, tinymce

TinyMCE allows us to list groups of styles. For example, the following would display a list of classes applied to DIVs or Ps.

```
{title: 'Block styles', filter: /^(div|p)\./}
```

I'd like to display a list of classes which:

```
- contain the word 'image'

- contain the word 'img'

- or are prefix by the tag img.
```

But I can't figure out the regex to do it :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know the first part.. to get all class names that start with 'image', you have to write this into the regex:

```
/^.image/
```